# Google Sheets formula to change a cells value based on another cells value

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, formula, formulas

I am currently muddled while trying to create a formula within Google Sheets that basically says:

*"If the value of cell E10 equals* "Levy" *then change the value of E11 cell to* "Monthly"*, if E10 equals anything other than **"Levy"** change the value of E11 to a drop down of menu* "Triannual" *and* "Quarterly"*

This is the formula I have so far which gets the first part done. I'm just stuck with creating the formula to create the drop down of the two other options if E10 = something other than the specified value.

> = IF(E10 = "Levy","Monthly","Triannual")

What else would I need to add?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Copy this to your script editor and save it:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var nota=e.range.getA1Notation()
  if(nota=="E10"){
  var val=e.range.getValue()
    if(val=="Levy"){
      s.getRange("E11").setDataValidation(null)
      s.getRange("E11").setValue("Monthly")
  }
      else{
  s.getRange('E11').clearContent()      
  var cell = s.getRange('E11');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Triannual', 'Quarterly']).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
   }}}
```

Comment: Do you know if I share a sheets document with a script like this in it, will the shared sheets contain/run the script without others effort?

Comment: It should. Try it.