# Script for Google sheet to change a cells value based on another cells value (in a column range)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the scenario:
Column E in my Googlesheet has a dropdown list of Yes and No. Everytime the user answers No, I want the corresponding cell in Column G to have the words "Not Applicable". But if user answers Yes, I want that cell in G to have another dropdown list of Yes and No.

I tried to build on the script that I got from this thread:
[Google Sheets formula to change a cells value based on another cells value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786590/google-sheets-formula-to-change-a-cells-value-based-on-another-cells-value#)

It's almost perfect, but I can't make it to work for a range (an entire column, preferrably). Any advice would be appreciated :)

Since I wasn't getting any success trying to tweak it for my own use, here's a copy code from the mentioned thread:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var nota=e.range.getA1Notation()
  if(nota=="E10"){
  var val=e.range.getValue()
    if(val=="Levy"){
      s.getRange("E11").setDataValidation(null)
      s.getRange("E11").setValue("Monthly")
  }
      else{
  s.getRange('E11').clearContent()      
  var cell = s.getRange('E11');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Triannual', 'Quarterly']).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
   }}}
```

And here's my dumb attempt:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var nota=e.range.getA1Notation()
  if(nota=="E2:E500"){
  var val=e.range.getValue()
    if(val=="No"){
      s.getRange("G2:G500").setDataValidation(null)
      s.getRange("G2:G500").setValue("Not Applicable")
  }
      else{
        s.getRange('G2:G500').clearContent()      
        var cell = s.getRange('G2:G500');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Yes','No']).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
   }}}
```

Comment: Post your code, that way it'll be easier to help

Comment: I wasn't actually getting any improvement by editing the script that I got from the other thread so I just added it in my original post as is :)

Comment: Post the code that you've tried not the code that you're referring.

Comment: Just in case you can't tell yet, I'm a total noob. I just went about replacing the ones I understand which in this case are just the texts in double quotes and cell references :|. I'll add my 'tweak' in a bit, for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop a range of cells, which is why the original script isn't working. `.getValue()` returns a single cell, you can't have a range (as in your edited script).

This script will look at the entire page and loop it each time. This is preferable because you don't have to keep data in order. In other words, you can jump around Column E and mark things "Yes" or "No" as they come up. Blank cells are ignored.

```js
  function addValidation() {

  // Get the spreadsheet and active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // Get the data as an Array you can iterate and manipulate
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Store a rule to use for the Data Validation to be added if ColE == "Yes"
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(["Yes", "No"]).build();

  // Loop the sheet
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

    // Test ColE. Note that the array is 0-indexed, so A=0, B=2, etc...
    // To change which columns you're testing, change the second value.
    if(data[i][4] == "Yes") {

      // If it's "Yes," add the Data Validation rule to Col G for that row.
      // Note that .getRange() is _not_ 0 indexed, which is why you need `i+1` to get the correct row

      sheet.getRange(i+1, 7).clear().setDataValidation(rule);

      // If ColE == "No," mark ColG as "Not Applicable"
    } else if(data[i][4] == "No") {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 7).clearDataValidations().setValue("Not Applicable");
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that this will *change* values as you change Col E. So, if you change a "Yes" to a "No," Col G will be changed to "Not Applicable."

Comment: Thank you, Brian! I have one minor issue with the code,.. When I answer Yes in E, the dropdown button sure appears but changing the answer to No mixes the "Not Applicable" text and the dropdown in G (and vice versa)... Any way to get rid of it? The code that I mentioned in my original post, actually doesn't have this issue?

Comment: Now when I answer No in one of the cells in Column E, I get this error: 

TypeError: Cannot find function clearDataValdation in object Range. (line 26, file "Code")

:{

Comment: Really? Make sure there is validation there beforehand. Sounds like you had already removed it before running the script. If you have a dummy sheet you want to share, I can take a look there, too. I can't get that error to replicate on my template.

Comment: Hey Brian, It's working perfectly on one of the copies that I made earlier! I believe I can manage tweaking the original copy. If I can't, I can just use the copy one :D  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
function checkData() {
      if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E" + i).getValue() == "No"){
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G" + i).setValue('Not Applicable');
      }
      else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G" + i).setValue('Applicable');
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you:)
Btw getting the range of 5000 rows will be VERY slow! Here is another way you can do it faster!

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR SHEET NAME AT THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE");
  var tsRows = parseInt(tsSheet.getLastRow());

     for (var i = 0; i < tsRows; i++) {
    function checkData() {
          if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E" + i).getValue() == "No"){
              SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G" + i).setValue('Not Applicable');
          }
          else{
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G" + i).setValue('Applicable');
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR SHEET NAME AT THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE");
  var tsRows = parseInt(tsSheet.getLastRow());

     for (var i = 0; i < tsRows + 1; i++) {
    function checkData() {
          if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E" + i).getValue() == "No"){
              SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G" + i).setValue('Not Applicable');
          }
          else{
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G" + i).setValue('Applicable');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey James, thank you for the prompt answer but I tried those two scripts and they don't work on my end,. I get nothing, not even errors,..

Comment: Can i see the code when implemented? You could add Logger.log(E[i])

Comment: Extra info: Is it because I have headers in the first row that would require minor adjustments to the script?

Comment: Change it to this -       for (var i = 0; i < tsRows + 1; i++) {

Comment: Just noticed your recent reply. Where do I add that ?

Comment: I'll add it to my answer now for you to copy and paste :)

Comment: Still no luck,. And oh, with my last comment I was actually referring to the Logger.log stuff :)

Comment: Oh at the bottom of the function, then check your logs and post them for me

Comment: I get an error saying "E" is not defined so I removed it and  ran the script. I got this when checking the log:  [17-09-20 20:16:00:444 HKT] [25006.0]

Not sure if I'm doing the right thing here lol

Comment: Make a copy of your sheet and remove all the sensitive information and send me the link and I'll try do it for you

Comment: No worries there as my sheet is super clean with no data yet. Just headers :) I'm on it

Comment: Okay, just send me the link with editing permission :)

Comment: So how do I add you now? I'm not so fond of using the sharing link for obvious reasons... Can I get your email addy? If that's too much, I'm sending the link here, fingers-crossed :)

Comment: I'd prefer the link :)  After you've had it posted for a min remove it

Comment: Oh, it looked like Brian got the answer right! Thank you for putting up with my noob-ness, James! Your thorough assistance is greatly appreciated :)